# In house type profile needs "iOS Development" certificate

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing

I have an Enterprise type apple account, I want to deploy to my testers without using device UDIDs. Then testers can manually trust my organization for testing. My Xcode version is **11.7**.

The error is:
[image]

Not sure why In house type also needs development type profile?

My steps are:

1. Create enterprise distribution certificates [link](https://help.apple.com/developer-account/#/devb17c2e0cd)

This step I generated `iPhone Distribution: xxx Limited` in keychain.

[image]

2. Create an app identifier.

[image]

3. Generate the profile for archiving.
   [image]
   [image]
4. Download the profile and double click to install it.
5. In Xcode, "Signing & Capabilities", used the profile just installed, then comes to error:
   [image]

Not sure what I have missed, please help! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the `Code Signing Identity` under `Build Settings/Signing` is `iOS Distribution` for the Release build configuration:

[image]

I had a similar problem caused by `iOS Developer` had being set for both Debug and Release build configurations.