# error: exportArchive: No signing certificate "iOS Development" found

Tags: ios, iphone, provisioning-profile, circleci, codesign

I am creating .ipa file from cli (circleci Mac agent). And am able to build the archive using below command
`xcodebuild -workspace XXX.xcworkspace -scheme XXX -sdk XXXX -configuration Release archive -archivePath ../build/XXX.xcarchive`
This build used "iPhone distribution : ****" code sign identity that i provisioned in before steps.

now am running the export command to create .ipa file surprisingly result says

```
error: exportArchive: No signing certificate "iOS Development" found
```

Error Domain=IDECodesignResolverErrorDomain Code=1 "No signing certificate "iOS Development" found"

And no where in the code mentioned "iOS development" certificate !!
Please help me what im missing with

Comment: Maybe something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63906153/6791677) will work?